# App_Browsers for specific directories/routes

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls, targeting

I have a site which uses the CSS Friendly Adapters for ASP.Net server controls.

Half of the site uses GridViews which have inline styling added to them. I do not want to change these controls and need them to work alongside the new pages until they can be re factored.

The other half of the site uses Bootstrap theming on the GridViews and as such the CSS friendly adapters are required.

Is there a way to target/ignore the Adapters in certain routes or directories?

Comment: I don't know, if you have found the solution for your problem. But I've faced same kind of issue. There is in-depth explanation of *.browser file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122(v=vs.100).aspx. I haven't found the way, how to capture browser by http request's "path" or "url". However there is possibility to capture by http header. Hope, it's helpful.